# Difference between lineTo & stroke

Tags: javascript, canvas, stroke

If `canvas` is `document.querySelector("canvas");` and `ctx` is `canvas.getContext("2d")`, what's the difference between `ctx.lineTo(x,y)` and `ctx.stroke()`?

Comment: One of em tells the canvas where to place the next set of coords. The other one tells the canvas to connect them. stroke doesn't take a coordinate, lineTo doesn't take a colour or width...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets assume a cursor that moves around the canvas, it records the path you provided but it draws only after you call stroke() or fill(). hope you got it!